# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

THe following query appears to fail to execute with the error - 
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. Where am I going wrong here?

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO darkweb (onionurl, sitetext) VALUES(%s, 'test') ON CONFLICT (onionurl) DO NOTHING)", (onion))
    connection.commit() 
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: What is the type and value of `onion`?

Comment: is `onion` a format string as well ? Let's see it

Comment: the type of onion is <class 'str'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a comma to your input tuple.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO darkweb (onionurl, sitetext) VALUES(%s, 'test') ON CONFLICT (onionurl) DO NOTHING)", (onion,))
connection.commit() 
cursor.close()
```

Or you could do this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO darkweb (onionurl, sitetext) VALUES(%s, 'test') ON CONFLICT (onionurl) DO NOTHING)", [onion])
```